# Adding a delay to an link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have search for this question and came to the conclusion that

```
$("a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).attr("href");
    setTimeout(function() {
    alert(link);
        window.location.href = link;
    }, 1000);
});
```

Should work the way i like however, when i use it will instead go to the location the link is set to.

Comment: Is the link there when you register the event?

Comment: Why exactly would you want to accomplish this if I may ask? As it breaks default functionality offered by the browser such as opening a link in a new tab by pressing Ctrl + Mouse 1.

Comment: the alert() is probably messing with you.  By the time you close the alert(), the 1 second time has already passed and you'll be redirected.  Remove the alert() and/or increase the timeout and you'll probably see that the code works as expected.  I cannot see anything obviously wrong with the code, at least not at a glance.  But without seeing the markup as well, it's hard to see.
Your code works fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/5ea9pr18/

Comment: @HaukurHaf as far as I know the `alert()` is synchronous and blocks all code execution at that point until dismissed.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right about the alert being syncronous.

Comment: "*when i use it will instead go to the location the link is set to*" - do you mean *before* the alert is shown?  Or as soon as you close the alert?  Is the alert shown after 1second?  Change your `alert` to a `console.log` and then just watch the browser console (with preserve log on)  - if you see the log, then it's working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is actually fine. Although, you may consider achieving that goal in a different way, since you break the default functionality of the `a` event.

```js
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).attr("href");
    setTimeout(function() {
       alert(link);
       window.location.href = link;
    }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="https://www.google.com">Click me</a>
```

Comment: Please add commentary as to what the "different way" you've used is and how it solves the issue for OP / the issue of "breaking the default functionality of the `a` event).

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Dev</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="https://localhost/sip-js"> test </a>
</body>
<script>
 $("a").click(function(e){
    var link = $(this).attr("href");
    setTimeout(function() {
    alert(link);
        window.location.href = link;
    }, 5000);
    e.preventDefault();
});
</script>
</html>
```